# Static data member of a class is Internal Linkage or External?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static, static-members

Static data member in a class(in C++) will be considered as internal linkage or external linkage ?
I did google but couldn't find out anything concrete for static member variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have external linkage. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbh4586z.aspx (thanks Raymond !).

Comment: Damn, I thought the class static members has the same *static linkage* as other `static` declared non-class variables. Very misleading..

Comment: @Rick nope! `static` has several different meanings depending on context... That's the committee being stingy with keywords :)

Comment: Microsoft documentation is not authoritative, and in this case, wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was also interested in this question recently, and I found this in N4659 (Some draft of C++17):

> § 6.5.5 In addition, a member function, static data member, a named class or enumeration of class scope, or an
> unnamed class or enumeration defined in a class-scope typedef declaration such that the class or enumeration
> has the typedef name for linkage purposes (10.1.3), has the same linkage, if any, as the name of the class of
> which it is a member.

So static data member can have internal or external linkage, decided by the class itself. For example, static data member of a class in unnamed namespace should have internal linkage.